# Proper mapping for a GET/POST request using WebClient and SpringBoot 3, new to WebClient

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-webclient

So I have been learning RequestMapping in Spring Boot 3 and I have gotten far along, however, for one project I have had, I needed to use a self-signed certificate, and this required that I move to something like RestTemplate. However I saw that RestTemplate will soon be deprecated as the upcomer WebClient has been taking its place (according to baeldung). Nonetheless, it is much more in-depth than what I have been learning, and despite seeing extremely basic tutorials, I have not seem to have solved my issue.

My issue is that I do not know how to properly map GET requests (and POST for that matter) for my application. I am building a react application and I am using my REST api to retrieve movies and information for the webapp. Before needing the SSL, I have taken the typical approach of having my controller:

CONTROLLER:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:3000", allowedHeaders = "*")
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/movies")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MovieController {

    private final MovieService movieService;
    private final WebClient webClient;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Movie>> getAllMovies(){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(movieService.getAllMovies(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{imbdId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Optional<Movie>> getSingleMovie(@PathVariable String imbdId){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(movieService.getSingleMovie(imbdId), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Where my movieService bean very simply queries the MongoDB repo for movies.

SERVICE

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MovieService {

    private final MovieRepository movieRepository;

    public List<Movie> getAllMovies(){
        return movieRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Optional<Movie> getSingleMovie(String imbdId){
        return movieRepository.findMovieByImdbId(imbdId);
    }
}
```

Now, given that I am now using WebClient as my Http client (as opposed to RestTemplate), I do not necessarily know how to approach this now. I understand I will most likely need to have another service specifically for WebClient to build these requests, but it is not straightforward for me when it comes to understanding it.

I already have a WebClient bean customized and configured, which should be able to handle the requests. I understand the Mono/Flux API is quite important, since, for example, I want to respond with List of Movie(which I receive as JSON on the frontend), but how this is implemented is a bit tricky. How would I respond with the 200 OK, as well as a compatible list of movies in the nice JSON format I need supported.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that this question was just a lack of knowledge of Ssl, and what my api was meant to achieve. I secured my api in spring with a simple Ssl certificate, and it served getRequests properly

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the example in this picture:
[image]

Change the Return Type to ResponseEntity.

Explanation:
Perform a get() requests with this uri and retrieve the resulting body as a Mono. Block() this method until the request is done.